# Multiple items are selected in an Android ListView as you scroll it

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView and I have modified it so when you press on a list item, the list item background color changes and the list focus is centered on the item. Everything works as expected and there are no issues.

However, if you scroll the list, then you will find another list item with its background changed, and another, and another, cyclically. From what I understand, the items in the ListView are being recycled, and this is the reason why this is happening.

For example, my list contains 12 items that can be displayed on the screen, before you need to scroll. If you select the first item, then the 15th element will also get its background changed, as you scroll the list on the actual device.

Does anybody know how to address this problem such as to have only one item having its background changed instead of this repeating pattern of additional "selected items"?

Here's the code for it:

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, long id) {
            //this deselects the previously selected item (changes its background to the default one)
            if(listItemPosition!=null) {
                previouslySelected = vehicleListArrayAdapter.getView(listItemPosition,previousView,parent);
                previouslySelected.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.applicationBackground));
            }
            //verify if the pressed item has been set as itemPosition and if not, set it
            if (listItemPosition == null || listItemPosition != position){
                listItemPosition = position;
                previousView = vehicleListArrayAdapter.getView(position,view,parent);
            }
            //set the selection to the listItemPosition (if we subtract 5, we set the focus on the center of the ListView)
            realTimeVehicleListView.setSelection(listItemPosition-5);
            //focus the list on that item
            realTimeVehicleListView.requestFocus();
            //change the background color of the selected item to emphasize it
            currentlySelectedListItem = vehicleListArrayAdapter.getView(listItemPosition,view,parent);
            currentlySelectedListItem.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.selectedItem));
```

Here's some code trying to use a flag:

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, long id) {
            vehicleListItemSelected = true;
            //this deselects the previously selected item (changes its background to the default one)
            if(listItemPosition!=null) {
                previouslySelected = vehicleListArrayAdapter.getView(listItemPosition,previousView,parent);
                previouslySelected.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.applicationBackground));
            }
            //verify if the pressed item has been set as itemPosition and if not, set it
            if (listItemPosition == null || listItemPosition != position){
                listItemPosition = position;
                previousView = vehicleListArrayAdapter.getView(position,view,parent);
            }
            //set the selection to the listItemPosition (if we subtract 5, we set the focus on the center of the ListView)
            realTimeVehicleListView.setSelection(listItemPosition-5);
            //focus the list on that item
            realTimeVehicleListView.requestFocus();
            //change the background color of the selected item to emphasize it
            if (vehicleListItemSelected){
                currentlySelectedListItem = vehicleListArrayAdapter.getView(listItemPosition,view,parent);
                currentlySelectedListItem.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.selectedItem));
                vehicleListArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                vehicleListItemSelected = false;
            }
```

EDIT: It's even worse than I originally thought. If you select the first item, its background gets changed, then you scroll the list randomly and return back to the first item, it's no longer selected. Instead, some other item is selected, maybe the 2nd or 3rd item, it has its background changed instead of the first one, that you actually selected.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a variable to the adapter saying whether or not it is selected.
At the start set selected to false for each element and then when the user clicks on the item in the list. set the boolean to true for that position in the list used in the adapter. This will prevent recycling.

Each time an item is selected and you pass the true variable, remember to use notifyDatastChanged on the adapter

Comment: Well, I tried to do it, but it doesn't work. Here's my code:

`if (vehicleListItemSelected){
                    currentlySelectedListItem = vehicleListArrayAdapter.getView(listItemPosition,view,parent);
                    currentlySelectedListItem.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.selectedItem));
                    vehicleListArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    vehicleListItemSelected = false;
                }`

I can't post more due to reply character limit, but it doesn't work.

Comment: use VIEWHOLDER @RobertRuxandrescu